# Why my care instead of your care?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, cinema

In the movie called [Big Hero 6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Hero_6_%28film%29), the white robot Baymax is the inflatable healthcare companion robot. He takes care of whoever needs help. And once done, the person taken care should say,

> I'am satisfied with **my** care

I'm not native english, so that a question came up: why the person received care from the robot saying "my care" instead of "your care"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this context, the person is saying they are satisfied with the care they received, so it is considered "their" care. Telling Baymax "I am satisfied with your care" although it could be used to mean "I am satisfied with the care you have provided" is a less common way of saying it and would probably confuse the listener.